# SQL Server to .Net Decimals with EF6 dDatabase first issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm currently reading data from a SQL Server stored procedure and it is returned as `Decimal(38, 20)`.

I know that the .Net decimal is `(28, 10)`, but the model classes generated for this by EF are showing `Decimal?`. When I query the table, the code throws a conversion overflow error, because it is trying to place the SQL Server decimal in the .Net decimal field.

Is there an easy way to convert it to .Net decimal through the data context? Basically I don't have access to modify the SQL Server datatype.

SQL Server datatype:

```
 Amount Decimal(38, 20)
```

Entity

```
public class EntityClass
{
     public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And when I call

```
 var eee =  _context.EntityClass
                    .Select(x => x.Amount)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I get

> Conversion Overflow Error

Comment: What version of EF?  How many significant digits do you need to preserve? What value in the database is causing the overflow?

Comment: This one for sure is an issue (-4210862852.86000000000000000000).

Comment: Yep.  I can repro that. What version of EF?

Comment: why you don't use just double on your class? public double? Amount { get; set; }

Comment: @YairI double isn't `just`, it will make things far worse. It has a *smaller* range than Decimal and is guaranteed to cause rounding errors. It won't affect this error either - the field's range is simply too long

Comment: @YairI Even if EF somehow converted the `numeric(38,20)` to a double, it would work only by truncating the fractional part and wouldn't work at all for numbers outside double's range

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  Its using EF6

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug or limitation with .NET's SqlClient.  Here's a repro:

```
    using (var con = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=tempdb;Integrated Security=true"))
    {
        con.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("select cast(4210862852.86 as decimal(38,20))  val", con);
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            rdr.Read();

            var val = rdr.GetDecimal(0);
            Console.WriteLine(val);
        }
    }
```

The issue is that this number

```
select cast(cast(4210862852.86 as decimal(38,20)) as varbinary(20))
```

is stored, and transmitted over the wire as

```
0x261400010000D877FB4DEE8B51699A5005000000
```

And SqlClient will refuse to convert any decimal with a non-zero in that last 4 bytes:

```
internal decimal Decimal
{
    get
    {
        ThrowIfNull();

        if (StorageType.Decimal == _type)
        {
            if (_value._numericInfo.data4 != 0 || _value._numericInfo.scale > 28)
            {
                throw new OverflowException(SQLResource.ConversionOverflowMessage);
            }
            return new decimal(_value._numericInfo.data1, _value._numericInfo.data2, _value._numericInfo.data3, !_value._numericInfo.positive, _value._numericInfo.scale);
        }
        if (StorageType.Money == _type)
        {
            long l = _value._int64;
            bool isNegative = false;
            if (l < 0)
            {
                isNegative = true;
                l = -l;
            }
            return new decimal((int)(l & 0xffffffff), (int)(l >> 32), 0, isNegative, 4);
        }
        return (decimal)this.Value; // anything else we haven't thought of goes through boxing.
    }
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBuffer.cs

I opened an issue against .NET Core here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37592

Answer (score -1):

in your ApplicationDbContext you should add

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<EntityClass>()
            .Property(p => p.Amount )
            .HasColumnType("decimal(28,20)");
```

Comment: _"I don't have access to modify the SQL Server datatype"_

Comment: The OP's problem is that the database field's precision *38*. `Decimal` can handle up to 28. `HasColumnType("decimal(28,20)")` won't change the precision of an existing field either, so it won't affect what values can be stored there.